# How to change place order button text for paypal in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I have a question about changing text of place_order.

Check out page will reload form by update_checkout Event, So the place_order text will change back to original text ‘proceed to Paypal’.

I've tried to use Jquery and function hook to change text but still change back.

```
function woo_custom_order_button_text() {
    return __( 'Your new button text here', 'woocommerce' ); 
}
```

How can I change the text of #place_order by not disable the update_checkout Event?

Answer (score 2):

To change the place order button text when Paypal is the chosen payment gateway use the following:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_checkout_paypal_pay_button_text', 10, 3 );
function change_checkout_paypal_pay_button_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if( 'Proceed to PayPal' === $text ) {
        $translated_text = __('Your custom text', $domain); // <== Here the replacement txt
    }
 
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Now to change the place order text for others payment gateways, you will use in addition the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', 'custom_checkout_place_order_text' );
function custom_checkout_place_order_text( $button_text ) {
        return __( 'Your custom text here', 'woocommerce' ); // <== custom text Here
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.